# JSF 2 reload tab when new tab opened with same application

Tags: session, jsf

I have JSF 2 application (@SessionScoped). When I'm opening a new tab for another user in same browser nothing happens in the "old" tab, but I can't make operations in it, it's kind a stuck. But if I'm refreshing the "old" tab it gets new session (same as in the "new" tab) and works OK.

The question is: how I can reload the old tab at the moment when new tab in same browser was opened?